# Improve JQuery function for make it able to accept variables

Tags: jquery, html, function, toggle

This code is intended to be able to toggle between showing and hiding an element depending on its ID.

I'm trying to transform the code to make it possible to give it easily the variables like in standard javascript functions.

Like this, I would be able to employ this function always that I want to hide or show an html element just calling the function and giving it a ID as a attribute.

I'm trying this version of the code but It doesn't work. But I'm giving the ID's of the elements I want to change so there is a mistake.

```
var x;
x=$(document);
x.ready(init);

function init(){
            var x;
            x=$("#titulo1");  // Here is the ID of the control element
            x.click(Qocult_most("#subtitulo1"));
            }

function Qocult_most(id){  //Show and scrolls down till the page's end
            var x;
            x=$(id); //Here is the ID element to show
            x.toggle(50);
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#STH").offset().top }, 1000);
                    }
```

And the HTML body who calls this JQuery is:

```
 <body>

 <div id="titulo1" class="contenedor"> I'm title 1  
 <div id="subtitulo1">  Text to show as a sub-menu when title 1 is clicked</div>
 <div id="titulo2" class="contenido"> I'm title 2 

</div>

</div>


</body>
```

Comment: `Function(id) {variable = id; actions;}` isn't a valid JavaScript function definition. Did you mean to write `function ID(variable, actions)`?

Comment: It was just a way to show what I wanted to reach. Now I've edited the question with some improvements. I'm not quite sure if this design is in the good way...

Comment: The question has been corrected and improved to be on topic an proper to the site's rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function init(){
  var x = $("#check");  // Here is the ID of the control element
  x.click(
    function() {
      Qocult('#most');
    }
  );
}

function Qocult(id) {  //Show and scrolls down till the page's end
  var x = $(id); 
  x.toggle(500);
  $("html, body").animate(
    { scrollTop: $("#STH").offset().top }, 1000
  );
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

Comment: I've used this schema to make it work but still it doesn't work. I'm still trying. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Not quite the same - I'm passing a function, which will call `Qocult` when clicked. You're actually calling `Qocult` in `init`

Comment: Such difficult. I'll try to find another solution. Perhaps flash. It doesn't seem possible to do this in JQuery